# Как масштабировать иконку в onTouchEvent?

Tags: android, swipe, ontouchlistener, vector-drawable

Пытаюсь сделать такое swipe menu как в гайдлайнах. Рисую с помощью `canvas`, иконка `vectorDrawable`. Не понимаю, каким образом масштабировать иконку с откликом на событие перетаскивания?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
private void drawButton(Canvas c, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
    float corners = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 3,
            resources.getDisplayMetrics());


    View itemView = viewHolder.itemView;
    Paint p = new Paint();


    RectF rightButton = new RectF(itemView.getLeft(), itemView.getTop(), itemView.getRight(), itemView.getBottom());

    p.setColor(Color.parseColor("#BDBDBD"));
    c.drawRoundRect(rightButton, corners, corners, p);
    drawIcon(c, rightButton);

    if (buttonShowedState == ButtonsState.RIGHT_VISIBLE) {
        buttonInstance = rightButton;
    }
}


private void drawIcon(Canvas c, RectF button) {
    mMyVectorDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, mMyVectorDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), mMyVectorDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
    mMyVectorDrawable.setTint(Color.parseColor("#C62828"));
    c.translate(button.centerX() + 470, button.centerY() - 70);
    mMyVectorDrawable.draw(c);

}



@Override
public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
    if (actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_SWIPE) {
        viewHolder.itemView.setTranslationX(dX);
        setTouchListener(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
        drawButton(c, viewHolder);
    } else {
        super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
    }
}
```

Comment: приведите код что-ли.. так боюсь вам не подскажу ничего...